# how to know tables that data had been adden whithin them in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working in a project that has been already started ,I need to do some tests in the database, if someone knows the query to retrieve tables that had recieved data lastly, affeced by INSERT INTO queries ???

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really looking for which *table* was last affected, try `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
select table_schema,table_name,update_time,table_rows 
from information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY update_time DESC  LIMIT 20;
```

Unfortuately, that doesn't seem to have any information about what kind of query affected the data ... it could have been a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` query instead.

Comment: thanks for giving help, I did't get result i wanted, just its showing me mysql table, and not tables inside my database,*